# Split an array into columns in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to reduce array so I have its' values in 'columns' where the first value lives in the first column, the second one in the second, etc. until it wraps, so that for example the fourth value is in the first of three columns.

```
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].in_columns(3)
=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: You must add the code you've attempted to solve your problem to your question.

Comment: Effort so far ? please post the code you have tried so far

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A functional one-liner:

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

cols = 3

res = [...Array(cols).keys()].map(c => a.filter((_, i) => i % cols === c));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you it works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by taking the remainder with the wanted count.

```js
Array.prototype.inColumns = function (count) {
    return this.reduce((r, v, i) => ((r[i % count] = r[i % count] || []).push(v), r), []);
}

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].inColumns(3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new `in_columns` method for the `Array.prototype`, using simple for loops:

```js
Array.prototype.in_columns = function(n) {
  var result = new Array(n).fill().map(() => []);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    result[i % n].push(this[i]);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].in_columns(3));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use below reducer to achieve that

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

const toColums = (arr, count) => {
  return [...arr.reduce((a, b, i) => a.set(i % count, (a.get(i % count) || []).concat(b)), new Map).values()];
};

console.log(toColums(arr, 3));
```